# .inArray passing a variable to check against an array JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a function where I am iterating over each `.marker`, creating a variable that contains its classes.

I also have an array named `checkBoxClasses`.

What I'm having a problem with is checking the classes within the variable `markerClasses` against the array `checkBoxClasses`. I want to break down the variable `markerClasses` and pass each individual class through the array.

Here's the code so far:

```
$('.marker').each(function () {

      var markerClasses = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');

            if ($.inArray(markerClasses , checkBoxClasses) > -1) {

                //do something

            };
});
```

Comment: "I am aware that you cant pass a variable through this so Im asking for a way to do this." to do something with what ?

Comment: pass seperate class values through the inArray and if they match the checBoxClasses array, then //do something.

Comment: loop on the array `markerClass` then use inarray

Comment: do you want to 'do something' when all the `markerClasses` match the `checkBoxClasses` or just 1 or more?

Comment: I want to break down the variable markerClasses and pass each individual class through the array. Thats the best way to do it I think.

Comment: @CecilTheodore: Okay, that's clear now. I think I've answered that. (I also edited that into the question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) checks for a *single value* in an array. Since the value of the array reference `markerClasses` isn't in `checkBoxClasses`, it will always return -1.

It's unclear what you want to do. If you want to know if *any* of the `markerClasses` entries is in `checkBoxClasses`, you'll need to loop them and check them individually, breaking on the first match. If you want to check if they're *all* in `checkBoxClasses`, it's similar but you break on the first non-match.

E.g., to see if *any* of the element's classes is in `checkBoxClasses`:

```
var markerClasses = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
var found = false;
$.each(markerClasses, function(index, value) {
    if ($.inArray(value, checkBoxClasses) !== -1) {
        found = true;
        return false;
    }
}
if (found) {
    // At least one of the element's classes was in `checkBoxClasses`
}
```

To see if *all* of the element's classes are in `checkBoxClasses`:

```
var markerClasses = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
var allFound = true;
$.each(markerClasses, function(index, value) {
    if ($.inArray(value, checkBoxClasses) === -1) {
        allFound = false;
        return false;
    }
}
if (allFound) {
    // *All* of the element's classes was in `checkBoxClasses`
    // (Including the case where the element didn't have any.)
}
```

Comment: edited the bottom line to make this more informative. I want to pass separate classes through this to see if they match.

Comment: @CecilTheodore: I'm afraid the question is still fairly unclear. Hopefully the answer addresses it anyway.